# "Folder names" vs "folders' names"

Tags: grammar

Let's say, we are talking about folders in a computer. What is a correct way to refer to the names of multiple folders?

ex:
- Folder names are incorrect.
or
- Folders' names are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

What we are dealing with here in my understanding is the use of possessives in combination with compound nouns. According to this [Grammar Tip](https://ontariotraining.net/grammar-tip-possession-with-compound-nouns-and-pronouns/), you should use *Folders' names*, since you have multiple folders "possessing" these names. *Folder names* would then be just one folder with multiple names.

Comment: The linked article is talking about compounds which are conjunctions, like *Mary and Phil's house*. A *folder name* is not the combination of a name and a folder, but rather is the name of the folder. *Folders' names* is rather unnatural except in specific contexts where there is a need to emphasize a plurality of names for a plurality of folders.